# How to get Json value in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to get following values of url from json

```
{
    "method":"create",
    "trace":"asdf/asdf/asdfasd",
    "order": {
        "ref":"asdfasdfasfasdfasd",
        "url":"https://domain.com/gateway/process.html?o=asdasdasdasd9"
    }
}
```

I am trying to get it using the following code:

```
var jsonData = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
string url = jsonData["url"].Values<string>()
```

It is not working, I also tried `JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsonData.ToString());` but I am not able to get it working either. (I get null exception for `string url2 = jsonData["url"].Value<string>();`)

Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: Define "not working". If you have error messages, show them.

Comment: is it not because the `url` property is in a nested object?

Comment: I get null exception for `string url2 = jsonData["url"].Value<string>();` while i have the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your url is here:

```
string url = jsonData["order"]["url"].ToString();
```

Comment: This is not working unless i add .Tostring(). This is the mistake i was makeing `jsonData["order"]["url"].ToString()`

Comment: thanks, i improved my answer.  Havn't seen it in Linqpad, it worked there :)